# FluentValidation, can I make a rule dependent on two other rules?

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I would like to make a third rule run only if the first two rules pass.
For example if I have something like this:

```
RuleFor(e => e.FirstType)
    .Length(2, 10)
    .MustAsync(async (value, token) => await TypeIsValid(value, context))
    .WithMessage("First Type is not valid.");

RuleFor(e => e.SecondType)
    .Length(2, 10)
    .MustAsync(async (value, token) => await TypeIsValid(value, context))
    .WithMessage("Second Type is not valid.");

When(e => {some condition here}, () =>
{
    RuleFor(e => e)
        .MustAsync(async (cw, token) => await TypesAreUnique(cw, context))
        .WithMessage("Already exists");
});

RuleFor(e => e.Property3)
    .Length(2, 10)

RuleFor(e => e.Property4)
    .Length(2, 10)
```

I don't think `When()` is the right way. I'm just using it to express intent.
In place of `{some condition here}` I would like some logic that checks if the first two rules passed. If either failed I don't do the third check.

DependentRule doesn't work because I have two rules that the third depends on.

CascadeMode.Stop doesn't help because I need all other rules to run.

Any ideas?

Comment: Idea: Put the first two rules in a RuleSet, and the third rule in another RuleSet. Execute a validation for the first RuleSet, and capture the ValidationResult. If no errors in the ValidationResult, execute the validation for the second RuleSet. If errors, don't run the second RuleSet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dependent rules.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotNull().DependentRules(() => {
 RuleFor(x => x.Forename).NotNull();
 });
```

You can refer this link for complete documentation.

[link](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/dependentrules.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since the check for the uniqueness of both types already occurs via a custom method (instead of built-in rules), you can call that `TypesAreUnique` method from an override of the `ValidateAsync` method.

First call `base.ValidateAsync` to check whether the rule based validations succeeded.
If none of these reported an error about the `FirstType` or `SecondType` property,
then call that `TypesAreUnique` method and add an error when appropriate.

```
public override async Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(
    ValidationContext<YourClass> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
    )
{
    var validationResult = await base.ValidateAsync(context, cancellationToken);
    
    if (!validationResult.Errors.Any(
            o => o.PropertyName == nameof(YourClass.FirstType) || o.PropertyName == nameof(YourClass.SecondType)
        )
        && !await TypesAreUnique(context.InstanceToValidate, cancellationToken)
        )
    {
        validationResult.AddError("Already exists");
    }

    return validationResult;
}
```